# Netstat Foreign Address Shows MAIL: mySQL

Tags: mysql, netstat

I am running a dedicated mySQL 5 server on Windows 2008.  I believe a bot may be installed on the server sending out emails.  If I run a Netstat -a on the server, i am seeing these types of entries.  What is this?

```
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50573             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50575             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50580             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50669             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50813             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:50814             ESTABLISHED
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:51034             TIME_WAIT
TCP    x.x.x.x:3306     mail:51035             TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: `mail` hostname of a machine accessing your mySQL server. Use `netstat -an` to show the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

No. port 3306 is MySQL. and you're establishing a series of TCP connections to it, which by necessity have to come **FROM** a tcp port. `mail` is simply how your system resolves its own ip.

If it was a bot sending mails, you'd see a lot of foreign ips as the destination IP, generally to port 25 (SMTP).